# iOS (Swift) project needs to read an Azure SQL database

Tags: ios, swift, azure

I am creating an iOS project that needs to read a SQL database in Azure. I have the database Server location, port, username, and password. I don't need to write to the database, just read it. I am more familiar with Firebase or Parse and have never used Azure. How do I even go about starting this? I tried the sample project that Azure makes for you but I don't have any tables? Do I need this? Any help would be welcome.

Comment: I would really advise you to create a webservice layer using ASP .Net Web API that will read the information from the database and provide REST-like calls to your application. It will give you much more flexibility in the future and you won't have to save your database credentials in the app. It will also solve many problems like firewalls and stuff.

Comment: @ThibaultD. what's the best way of doing this? I figured an API would be the best choice.

Comment: as I said, creating an ASP .Net Web API using visual studio I would advise, and have it run in Azure as an App Service

Answer (score 2):

[Azure Mobile App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/) can connect with your existing SQL database
[this thread explains the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441601/how-to-use-azure-mobile-app-service-with-existing-sql-database) where you use the existing SQL database. With this option Azure manages most of the inner workings for you.

If you want to build the Rest API from "scratch" using your existing SQL database You have some more options: 
[Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/) allows you to publish API's securely and at scale, A server less Azure Function like the example in this article [Rest API with Azure Functions and Azure SQL Database](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/features/json/azure-function-rest-api#rest-api-with-azure-functions-and-azure-sql-database) or build a rest API using an [Azure Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint) which doesn't require you to write code. You could also use Nodejs or many other tools you just need to evaluate what would work best for your use case.