# Connecting Azure SQL Database with iOS Swift

Tags: swift, azure-sql-database

I'm new to Azure and to SQL Database, I always used Firebase for my apps, now I want to switch and I can't find any way to connect an app to my database.

Comment: Found [iOS (Swift) project needs to read an Azure SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38535621/205233) simply using your post title as a google search query. Looks like this question has already been asked and answered.

Comment: Hi @S_dnomseD, is that tutorial  you want?

Comment: Thanks @S_dnomseD, can you please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ref the link [iOS (Swift) project needs to read an Azure SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38535621/ios-swift-project-needs-to-read-an-azure-sql-database) which @Filburt provided in the comment.

You also could ref this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f50195df-0fab-4361-82ac-e75a338b69cc/connect-to-azure-sql-database-from-ios-app-written-in-swift, it's answer provide more details can help you.

HTH.