# How to connect a Xamarin app to a SQL Azure DB

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-sql-database

I have created an SQL Azure DB and I want to connect a new Xamarin app that's supposed to run on Android, to it.
I am new to Xamarin an I couldn't figure out a simple way to do it from the tutorials online.

What's the simplest way to fetch data from a SQL DB in Azure, using Xamarin app?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

Comment: this link doesn't talk about Azure or about SQL Azure DB. saw such guides but couldn't apply them  - I need something more specific for my needs

Comment: SQL on Azure is just a SQL db hosted in Azure, and the same general rules about connecting from a remove client apply.  You may want to look at this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441601/how-to-use-azure-mobile-app-service-with-existing-sql-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Azure Mobile App service with existing SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441601/how-to-use-azure-mobile-app-service-with-existing-sql-database)

Comment: @CSharpRocks Hi- all those guides are quite confusing. I have an existing SQL DB in Azure and i want to create a brand new Xamarin app (that will run on android) that will be also able to access and update the DB. Are the following lines what i need? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-login-with-web-api-using-azure-sql-server-part-one/ http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-login-with-web-api-using-azure-sql-server-part-two/

Comment: Hi darThoughts! You'll want to create an Azure API app for your mobile app to reach your Azure SQL Database. I have a sample app in GitHub that shows how to create an API App connect it with an Azure SQL Database and then communicate with it via a Xamarin app: https://github.com/brminnick/XamList. Feel free to open a GitHub Issue in this repo if you have any questions, and I'll be happy to help you out!

Answer (score 4):

## Answer

You'll need to create an Azure API App. The Xamarin app will use this REST API to interact with the database.

Never connect a mobile app directly to a remote database using the database's `connection string`, because this opens up the potential for database corruption. For example, if the mobile app user has a poor internet connection, and they are connecting directly to the database, the app may not be able to finish executing a database query. An API will ensure that no database corruption happens due to a poor internet connection.

## Sample Code + Walkthrough

I have a sample app and a walkthrough here that shows how to create an Azure API App, connect it to an Azure SQL Database and how to have the mobile app communicate with the REST API.

https://github.com/brminnick/XamList

Comment: Can you clarify - you use a lot of terms - Azure API App, mobile app ,  REST API. I currently have a SQL Azure DB. I want to create a Xamarin app (that's what I velive mobile app refers to) - so do I need to create another app (Azure API App) so the mobile app (Xamarin app) connects to it and the Azure API App will connect to SQL Azure? Also - where does the Azure API App have to be - in Azure or locally like the mobile app (aka Xamarin). And which of these stages does your guide explain how to do?

Comment: Hey @darkThoughts! Have you had a chance to look through the README on the link I posted. It shows how to spin up an API in Azure and contains the source code communicating between an API and a Xamarin app.

Comment: Not yet - i was trying to figure out the terminology so i will know what is it i am trying to create/achieve - so i know i understand you and we are talkin about the same thing. Like is  Azure API App and acutal application in Visual Studio or is it something i create in Azure portal?

Comment: Also - does the this two part guide talk about the same thing you are? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-login-with-web-api-using-azure-sql-server-part-one/ http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-login-with-web-api-using-azure-sql-server-part-two/

Comment: No worries! Sounds like you’re just getting started on your journey. Shoot me a message on Twitter @BrandonXamarin and I’ll help you get up and running!

Answer (score 2):

Per my understanding, you could leverage the **Data access** and **Client SDKs**
 features provided by [Mobile Apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-value-prop) for a simple way to achieve your purpose. You could follow the tutorials below for getting started with the Azure mobile app:

- Sign in Azure portal, [Create an Azure Mobile App backend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started#create-an-azure-mobile-app-backend)
- Add your data connection and link to your SQL Azure DB, for more details you could refer to [Configure the server project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started#configure-the-server-project)
- [Download and run the Xamarin.Android app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started#configure-the-server-project) working with your SQL Azure DB

Additionally, you could refer to Adrian hall's book [develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/) for a better understanding of Azure mobile apps.