# How to connect Azure Sql Database to my Xamarin.Forms.App?

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database

I am having an simple login page app in xamarin.forms ,two fields are there in login page namely UserName and Password. I having a table in SQL DataBase in AZURE which is holding username and Password. I have no idea how to connect DataBase to my app. Can you suggest any idea for this ?

Comment: This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015474/how-to-connect-a-xamarin-app-to-a-sql-azure-db

Comment: Please implement something like an API. Just some of lots of reasons: Having database credentials in an App is very concerning. If you need to scale in the future, an API will be much easier (and cheaper) to scale than a database. And if your app will get lots of users, the database will get lots of connections. You will not be able to optimize, for instance by using caching.

Answer (score 0):

This link talks about [Create a Xamarin.Forms app with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started), I think it can helps you.

And here is an another tutorial shows [How to build a Xamarin App connected to Azure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2017/09/11/how-to-build-a-xamarin-app-connected-to-azure/) and query、insert、update、delete data from the Azure SQL database.

For example:

**Query data**:

[image]

**Insert&Update:**

[image]

Hope this can helps you.